# Use value from axios function in another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have this async function to get an API access token:

```
const getAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
        const body = new URLSearchParams({
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            scope: 'manage:all'
        }).toString();

        const config = {
            headers: {
                Content_Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            auth: {
                username: clientId,
                password: clientSecret
            }
        };

        const { data: res } = await axios.post(
            `${baseUrl}/oauth2/token`,
            body,
            config
        );

        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

It return a promise which I use in the following function to log the access token to the console:

```
getAccessToken().then(res => {
    console.log(res.access_token);
});
```

It logs the token as a string.

Now I want to use this string value in another function in my code. Do I just call the function where I need the value like above and replace the `console.log` with `return`?

How do I use this string value in other parts of my code?

Comment: Either call the other function from `.then()` or assign it to a global variable. But make sure the other code doesn't run until after the Axios call has returned (e.g. in an event handler).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate a little bit on the global variable solution? I prefer not to call it from `.then()` as it will result in many nested functions that all depend on each other (harder to read code). Is there a more modular approach?

Comment: `.then(res => access_token = res.access_token)`

Comment: Thank you and I need to declare the `access_token` with `let` in the global scope?

Comment: You should, but just assigning it without declaring it will automatically make it a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it to call the function everywhere,

```
async function anotherFunction() { 
    const res = await getAccessToken();
    console.log(res.access_token)
}
```

Another way of doing this is to call the function on your page load save the token in `session/local storage/cookies` and use the token in other functions by fetching it from `session/local storage/cookies` to avoid making multiple API calls.

On page load

```
const res = await getAccessToken();
localStorage.setItem('token', res.access_token);


async function anotherFunction() { 
    const res = localStorage.getItem('token');;
    console.log(res.access_token)
}
```